# onClick javascript function shows only first child of wrapper

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, selector, element

I am learning javascript these days and I have a little problem with my code.

I have three elements on page `wrapper1`, `wrapper2` and `wrapper3` and every of these has its `trigger`and `redbox` element.

My goal is when the `trigger` is hit, it will show the `redbox` element corresponding to number.

Examples:
clicking `trigger1` inside `wrapper1` element shows up `redbox1` element,
`trigger2` inside `wrapper2` element shows up `redbox2` element etc.

The problem is, when I click on `trigger3` for example it always shows `redbox1` element. (as example shows).

What I am doing wrong? I am just a begginer.

```js
function showTheRedBox() {
  var theRedBox = document.getElementsByClassName('redbox');
  theRedBox[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {background: #222;}
.wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.trigger {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.redbox {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger" onclick="showTheRedBox();">trigger1</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah1</div>
wrapper1</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger" onclick="showTheRedBox();">trigger2</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah2</div>
wrapper2</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger" onclick="showTheRedBox();">trigger3</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah3</div>
wrapper3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop and a closure to access the `.wrapper` information for each onclick event. This method will work whether there are the same amount of children or not, and will always show the correct child.

Also, it is best to not use inline JavaScript attributes (e.g.  `onclick="showTheRedBox();"`) you should always assign your event handlers in your script for readability and maintainability.

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper'), i;
var redboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.redbox');

for(i = wrappers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  (function(wrapper){
    wrapper.querySelector('.trigger').onclick = function() {
      hideAll();
      wrapper.querySelector('.redbox').style.display = 'block';
    }
  })(wrappers[i]);
}

function hideAll() {
  for(i = redboxes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    redboxes[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper'), i;
var redboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.redbox');

for(i = wrappers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  (function(wrapper){
    wrapper.querySelector('.trigger').onclick = function() {
      hideAll();
      wrapper.querySelector('.redbox').style.display = 'block';
    }
  })(wrappers[i]);
}

function hideAll() {
  for(i = redboxes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    redboxes[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
body {background: #222;}
.wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.trigger {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.redbox {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">trigger1</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah1</div>
wrapper1</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">trigger2</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah2</div>
wrapper2</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">trigger3</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah3</div>
wrapper3</div>
```

---

This method will also work, but it will use more memory as it queries the DOM once more than the above solution.

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper'), i;
var redboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.redbox');

for(i = wrappers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  wrappers[i].querySelector('.trigger').onclick = function() {
    hideAll();
    this.parentNode.querySelector('.redbox').style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function hideAll() {
  for(i = redboxes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    redboxes[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper'), i;
var redboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.redbox');

for(i = wrappers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  wrappers[i].querySelector('.trigger').onclick = function() {
    hideAll();
    this.parentNode.querySelector('.redbox').style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function hideAll() {
  for(i = redboxes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    redboxes[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
body {background: #222;}
.wrapper {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.trigger {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.redbox {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">trigger1</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah1</div>
wrapper1</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">trigger2</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah2</div>
wrapper2</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">trigger3</div>
  <div class="redbox">hurrah3</div>
wrapper3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, everything working fine while applied on my website, but Im a bit lost in this code, I cannot properly understand these "i"s and "for"s. But can you please explain me how do I hide  redbox1 of first example (wrapper1, trigger1, and redbox1) while I hover out of trigger1.

Comment: `querySelectorAll(selector)` Returns a nodeList of elements that matched the CSS selector supplied. To apply an event handler to each element in a nodeList, you have to use a `for` loop to "loop through" the elements. If I understand the rest of your comment correctly, you want to [automatically hide the redbox associated with the wrapper when the user moves the mouse away from the trigger](http://jsfiddle.net/ts9k7ghg/)?

Comment: Yes I mean like this! Can you show me one more example for now when you leave wrapper it hides the redbox?

Comment: [`wrapper.onmouseout = function (e) { if( !wrapper.contains( window.event.relatedTarget )) redbox.style.display = 'none' }`](http://jsfiddle.net/ts9k7ghg/3/)

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why, but in my website and in liveweave it working only for first wrapper. Second doesnt hide content.

Comment: the code is mess, but here: http://liveweave.com/xGjTC7 just look at 'download' button.

Comment: [You were assigning the onmouseout event to the first wrapper, instead of the wrapper that is available within the closure.](http://liveweave.com/chEnEe)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have was that the method "getElementsByClassName", returns you an Array that contains all the elements of that class. So, when you where doing this:

```
theRedBox[0].style.display = 'block'
```

You were changing the display style of the **First** element of the Array, in this case "wrapper1".

Here's a modify version that functions whit the others wrappers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> MY TEST </title>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #222;
            }
            .wrapper {
              background: yellow;
              width: 100px;
              height: 100px;
            }
            .trigger {
              background: blue;
              width: 50px;
              height: 50px;
              position: absolute;
              margin-top: 50px;
              margin-left: 50px;
            }
            .redbox {
              background: red;
              width: 200px;
              height: 100px;
              margin-left: 100px;
              position: absolute;
              display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="trigger" onclick="showTheRedBox(0)">trigger1</div> <!-- When the onClick event is trigered the function "showTheRedBox receives a parameter , that parameter is the position of the element in the Array "theRedBox"-->
          <div class="redbox">hurrah1</div>
        wrapper1
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="trigger" onclick="showTheRedBox(1)">trigger2</div>
            <div class="redbox">hurrah2</div>
        wrapper2
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="trigger" onclick="showTheRedBox(2)">trigger3</div>
              <div class="redbox">hurrah3</div>
        wrapper3</div>

        <script>

            function showTheRedBox(wrapperNumber) {
                  var theRedBox = document.getElementsByClassName('redbox');
                  theRedBox[wrapperNumber].style.display = 'block';
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it works and it's simple. Thank you.